# Jasper-reports: grouping subdataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I have to do a Report with simple grouping. The data are received from Parameters ( JRBeanCollectionDataSource):

```
<subDataset name="zeilenset">
    <field name="deviceType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="deviceNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="approval" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="deviceName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="postalSite" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="devicerows" class="java.lang.Object"/>
<parameter name="myheadline" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

The report works, but iReport does not offer any of my subDataset fields for grouping.

Is there a way to group a subDataset?
Or is there another way to group Parameter driven lists than subDataset?

Comment: And what is a question?

Comment: Is there a way to to group a subDataset? Or is there another way to group Parameter driven lists than subDataset?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved myself.

Putting my data array into Parameters cause a non groupable subDataset:
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, **parameters**, new JREmptyDataSource());

Using the beanColDataSource transfer my data Array into groupable fields:
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, **beanColDataSource**);